# What to ping for Dead Gateway Detection

Tags: amazon-web-services, load-balancing, azure, ping, google-cloud-platform

I want to use **dead gateway detection** (DGD) in my multi-wan router. The question is: what should I ping?

Obviously it should be something which is always available to avoid false negatives.

I tried to use the Google DNS servers and failed. They have a percievied uptime of 100% when it comes to DNS queries, but they do not always repond well to pings. So I got a lot of false negatives.

There are other DNS Servers out there, but I am affraid that they will behave similarly to Google.

Another idea was to use/rent something from Amazon's AWS. The only thing is my router needs an IP (as opposed to a hostname) for DGD. Is there a way to ensure that one specific IP is always available with Amazon?

I am not bound to Amazon. Google, Azure or others are fine as well.

Pinging our website wont work since our hoster uses a load balancer.

Comment: Why would you not ping a router that is far enough out that it is unlikely to be up when you have no Internet, but close enough in that a failed ping is *highly likely* to mean your connection is unusable?  Like a core or outer edge router of your ISP?  Each link should be pinging something different, and too far away means false failures.

Comment: Good idea, but how to know which hop is a core router of my provider? And can I assume they will not change?

Comment: You can't be sure they won't change, but you can often observe the names and round-trip times using traceroute and get a good idea of the locations and roles of these routers by making observations over time.  If hops are unnamed, querying ARIN for the address space assignee often helps. Sometimes geolocating is useful but often points to ISP corporate offices.